# Replace strings in one column which match another column

Tags: r, string, if-statement

I have a dataframe that looks like this (but for every US county)

| Countyname | Neighbour County | Neighbour State |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Autauga County, AL | Chilton County | AL |
| Autauga County, AL | Dallas County | AL |
| Baldwin County, AL | Escambia County | FL |
| Catron County, NM | Apache County | AZ |

For all counties, if the neighbouring county is in the same state I want to replace the value in the Neighbour State column with a missing value NA, and if it's in a different state I want to keep it unchanged. I.e. I want to end up with something like this:

| Countyname | Neighbour County | Neighbour State |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Autauga County, AL | Chilton County | NA |
| Autauga County, AL | Dallas County | NA |
| Baldwin County, AL | Escambia County | FL |
| Catron County, NM | Apache County | AZ |

I was thinking of looping through each row and if the column 'Countyname' contains the entry in the column 'Neighbour State', replace the entry with NA (e.g. for the first row if 'Autauga County, AL' contains 'AL', replace 'AL' with NA). How would I go about this (or is there a more efficient way to do it as this feels clunky)?

Comment: Consider substring-ing out the last two characters in *CountyName* and compare it using `ifelse` with *Neighbor State*. Give it a try and come back with specific issues.

Comment: "I was thinking of looping through each row" - R is a vectorized language, so its functions do this by default.

Comment: I agree with @Phil, loops especially for loops are mostly avoidable in R and that's the beauty of this language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str_detect()` and `ifelse()`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df%>%
        mutate(Neighbour_State=ifelse(str_detect(Countyname, Neighbour_State), NA, Neighbour_State))
```

Or, preferably, `str_detect` and `replace()`

```
df%>%
        mutate(Neighbour_State=replace(Neighbour_State, str_detect(Countyname, Neighbour_State), NA))

#Or with pipes:

df%>%
        mutate(Neighbour_State=Neighbour_State%>%replace(., str_detect(Countyname, .), NA))
```

```
          Countyname Neighbour_County Neighbour_State
1 Autauga County, AL   Chilton County            <NA>
2 Autauga County, AL    Dallas County            <NA>
3 Baldwin County, AL  Escambia County              FL
4  Catron County, NM    Apache County              AZ
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure why the suggestions from the other users were not working (the table was left unchanged), but using replace worked.

Comment: Glad I could help. You can check this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

You don't need loop for this. You can use `dplyr` package instead:

```
data <- data %>%
  mutate(`Neighbour State` = ifelse(substr(Countyname, nchar(Countyname)-1, nchar(Countyname))== `Neighbour State`, NA,`Neighbour State`))
```

Comment: Ho yes, forgot substr was base R, I'll edit!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(stringr)
dat %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(
        Neighbour.State = dplyr::if_else(
            str_trim(unlist(str_split(dat$Countyname[1], ","))[2]) == Neighbour.State, "NA", Neighbour.State)
        )
```

```
          Countyname Neighbour.County Neighbour.State
1 Autauga County, AL   Chilton County              NA
2 Autauga County, AL    Dallas County              NA
3 Baldwin County, AL  Escambia County              FL
4  Catron County, NM    Apache County              AZ
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also use `regex` to find stateName from the county and use function `na_if` to replace values where it matches with the neighbour_county.  Like this

- regex `'.*\\,\\s'` will match everything upto a comma and a whitespace and replace it with `''` i.e. nothing.
- use mutate in combination with `ifelse` `na_if` `replace` `case_when` or any conditional function.

```r
df <- read.table(header = T, text = "Countyname Neighbour_County    Neighbour_State
'Autauga County, AL'    'Chilton County'    AL
'Autauga County, AL'    'Dallas County' AL
'Baldwin County, AL'    'Escambia County'   FL
'Catron County, NM' 'Apache County' AZ")

library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)

df %>% 
  mutate(Neighbour_State = na_if(gsub('.*\\,\\s','', Countyname, perl = T), Neighbour_State))
#>           Countyname Neighbour_County Neighbour_State
#> 1 Autauga County, AL   Chilton County            <NA>
#> 2 Autauga County, AL    Dallas County            <NA>
#> 3 Baldwin County, AL  Escambia County              AL
#> 4  Catron County, NM    Apache County              NM
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>